# Is there a word that means "finding X more attractive than X is"?

Tags: idioms

I am trying to think of a word that means finding something more attractive than it is, or finding it less unattractive than it is, but there's no expression that roll off the tongue.

For example:

> She got so wasted that Dino's horribly disfigured head looked more
>   attractive than it was.

Comment: How can one word mean that entire thing? That is a comparative phrase....

Comment: If you're talking specifically about being drunk, then there is the slang phrase "wearing [beer goggles](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=beer%20goggles)."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are words that indicate valuing something as more than it is worth, or to estimate something as larger or greater than it is. Those are *overvalue* and *overestimate*.

If there is a word that means to do this specifically with attractiveness, it is not a word in general usage.